# ignore some text boxes in a query

Tags: asp.net, sql, report

I have below code in code behind for `btnShowReport_Click`:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();  
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("username", txtUsername.Text);  
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("printer", ddlPrinter.Text);  
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("to", Date.convertDateSolar2Gregorian(txtDateFrom_datepicker.Text));
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("from", Date.convertDateSolar2Gregorian(txtDateTo_datepicker.Text));
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM JobLog WHERE UserName=@username and   PrinterName=@printer and TimeSubmitted between @to and @from";
```

I want when user doesn't fill some text boxes, in the query, the criteria of the textbox was ignored in query.
I hope you understand what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically build the SQL query using a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), however this makes your code prone to SQL Injection attacks and you should rather look at creating a stored procedure in SQL Server using [Dynamic SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

Here's the StringBuilder example though if you absolutely have to build the query in code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();

    string name = txtName.Text;
    string surname = txtSurname.Text;

    if (name.Length > 0)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Name", txtName.Text);
        parameters.Add("Name", name);
    }

    if (surname.Length > 0)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Surname", txtSurname.Text);
        parameters.Add("Surname", surname);
    }

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = GetSelectQuery("Customers", parameters);
    //Bind SqlDataSource1 to gridview etc...
}

private string GetSelectQuery(string table, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    var query = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    query.Append(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", table));

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
    {
        var param = parameters.ElementAt(i);
        if (i == 0)
            //Add the first parameter
            query.Append(String.Format(" WHERE {0}='{1}' ",param.Key, param.Value));
        else
            query.Append(String.Format(" AND {0}='{1}'", param.Key, param.Value));
    }
    return query.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this extension: [SqlBuilder Tutorial](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions/blob/master/docs/SqlBuilder.md)

With this extension you can build dynamic sql querys like this.

```
void DynamicSql(int? categoryId, int? supplierId) { 

   var query = SQL
      .SELECT("ID, Name")
      .FROM("Products")
      .WHERE()
      ._If(categoryId.HasValue, "CategoryID = {0}", categoryId)
      ._If(supplierId.HasValue, "SupplierID = {0}", supplierId)
      .ORDER_BY("Name DESC"); 
}
```